# "with John Locke interpreting the role of harbinger in inscribing the rules of economic behaviour within the laws of nature and God."

Tags: sentence-meaning, comprehension

> ... with John Locke interpreting the role of harbinger in inscribing the rules of economic behaviour within the laws of nature and God.

Does it mean that John Locke was one of the firsts who described the rules of economic behaviour within the laws of nature and God?

Comment: _I think that [...]_. Is it not the original sentence then? Or is _I think that..._ part of the sentence only? Like direct speech?

Comment: The phrase "I think that" is not a part of the sentence. I meant to say, I think that [...] means [John Locke was one of the firsts who described the rules of economic behaviour within the laws of nature and God] am I right.

Comment: The excerpt is not a complete sentence: it has no main verb. But yes, you've got it right. Locke is acting as a herald, or a precursor, or someone announcing the coming of something, by writing the rules...(etc.) By writing the rules in that way he played the part of a harbinger.

Comment: I don't think this question needs more contexts particularly. If you have basic knowledge about philosophy, such as empiricism, materialism, a priori, a posterirori, etc you can answer.